# How to populate a df column based on coditions that are number ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, conditional-statements

I would like to populate column df['category'] with numbers 1-52 when values of column df['values'] are less than x
So here values are days and category is weeknumber but not based on date but rather accumulation of days, every 7 days is a new week.
week = range of values from 1-52
range = multiples of 7 so 7, 14, 21, ... , 371

'category' ranges from 1 - 52
'values' ranges from 1 - 400

> If df['values'] < 7, then df['category'] = 1
> If df['values'] < 14, then df['category'] = 2
> If df['values'] < 21, then df['category'] = 3
> ....
> else df['category'] = 52

any df['values'] greater than 371 days can be considered df['category'] = 52

How can I write this?

I tried:

```py
week = list(range(1,53))

range = list(range(7,372,7))

for x in n:

    df.loc[(df['values'] < x), week]
```

and also

```py
df['category'] = np.select((df['values'] < x), week)
```

I would like the df to look like this:

| values | category |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 3 |
| 52 | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[20], [52], [400]], columns=['values'])
```

`df`:

```
    values
0   20
1   52
2   400
```

use following code:

```
df.assign(category=df['values'].divmod(7)[0].add(1).clip(upper=52))
```

output:

```
    values  category
0   20      3
1   52      8
2   400     52
```

Comment: Thank you! In this case what is [0] after .divmod(7) corresponding to the 'values' column and and the .add(1) to apply the result of the division to 'category' column ?

Comment: This also seemed to work, following a similar logic to @Panda Kim
df['category'] = np.ceil(df['values']/7)  
df.loc[df['category'] >52 ] = 52

Comment: You can find out what [0] means by just looking up `divmod` function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.divmod.html

Comment: or you can print `df['values'].divmod(7)` and `df['values'].divmod(7)[0]` by yourself